# Dependency injection with Laravel Facade

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have an error class which I have made a Facade and a ServiceProvider for.

I use it like this:

```
Err::getLastError();
```

I have also another class for file validation:

```
FileValidate::IsImage($this->getUpload());
```

I want to inject the Err facade into the `FileValidate` so that I use it like this:

```
FileValidate::Error()->getLastError();
```

How should I do this?

Now My approach is that, in `FileValidate` class I add a member:

```
function Error()
{
   return $this;
}
```

Though the above just returns the `FileValidate` object, thus I add another method:

```
function getLastError()
{
    return   Err::getLastError();
}
```

But then for each method of `Err`, I should make an alternative in `FileValidate` and all Err like the above example. I need a more dynamic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `FileValidate::Error()` method return the error class rather than an instance of `FileValidate`:

```
function Error()
{
    return app()->make('Err');
}
```

This will return your error object which should have whatever methods on it that you need without having to duplicate them on another class for no reason.

Another alternative could be to add the error object into the `FileValidate`'s constructor:

```
public function __construct(Err $error) {
    $this->$error = $error;
}
```

After updating your file validate's service provider, you could then just return *that* object from your `Error` method:

```
public function Error()
{
    return $this->error;
}
```

Comment: can I ask you if is there a way to add a constructor to a facade in Laravel? Becuase how should a __construct() work when the object is accessed throguh Facace?

Comment: You don't add the constructor to the facade, add it to the underlying class that the facade is referencing